# Does Quorum works with Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, windows, quorum

As the tittle says, I would like to make a demo but I don´t know if Quorum supports windows.

Comment: Quorum is based on Ethereum and question about it do not necessarily are off-topic here.

Comment: The simplest way to do is to use a Linux VM in your Windows with virtualbox and vagrant. See quick start on https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Ismael the question whether Quorum works on windows is not particularly relevant to this forum...

Comment: @Joël The question is about Quorum support of Windows. Since it is a version of go-ethereum with extra features for me it is relevant. Go-ethereum does support windows so it is possible for them to support it. For me is an interesting topic, but let the people vote and decide.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively yet, but if you are on Windows 10, you could try enabling the Windows Subsystem For Linux component, install Ubuntu and setup quorum there.